# PostgreSQL - parse nested JSON argument

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm pretty green in my Postgres experience so I hope this isn't too remedial :)

If nested JSON is passed as a variable in PostgreSQL, can it be parsed without first dumping it into a temporary table?

Let's say I wanted to get the mother's names from the sample below. What would the SELECT statement look like?

```
do
$$
declare persons json = 
'{
        "name":"Sally",
        "spouse":
        {
            "name":"Alex",
            "parents":
            {
                "father":"Rafael",
                "mother":"Ofelia"
            },
            "phones":
            [
                {
                    "type":"work",
                    "number":"619-555-1212"
                },
                {
                    "type":"cell",
                    "number":"012-345-6789"
                }
            ]
        }
    }';

begin
    
/* ??? */

end;
$$
```

Many thanks in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

It can be parsed, but the question is what will you do with the response?

If you just want to see it in the results, then the quickest is to define your json in a CTE:

```
with p as (
 select '{
        "name":"Sally",
        "spouse":
        {
            "name":"Alex",
            "parents":
            {
                "father":"Rafael",
                "mother":"Ofelia"
            },
            "phones":
            [
                {
                    "type":"work",
                    "number":"619-555-1212"
                },
                {
                    "type":"cell",
                    "number":"012-345-6789"
                }
            ]
        }
    }'::jsonb as persons
)
select persons->'spouse'->'parents'->>'mother'
  from p;

 ?column? 
----------
 Ofelia
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hey Mike, The CTS  is exactly what I needed! I'm going to wind up inserting the parsed JSON into a table. We were previously putting the JSON in a temp table and then processing it, but I heard the temp table was unnecessary. I was just struggling to figure out how to manage parsing the JSON without a table to lean on, which of course the CTE handles perfectly well. Thanks a million!

Comment: Alternatively, `select persons#>>'{spouse,parents,mother}' from p;`